# Regular expressions in SQL?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to use a regular expression in Oracle 11g SQL to find records that do not match it. The regular expression is:

```
/([A-Z]{3})+([0-9])\w+/g
```

The SQL I want to use would be something like:

```
select
  stu_code
  ,stu_insc
from
  intuit.ins_stu
where
  stu_insc not like ('/([A-Z]{3})+([0-9])\w+/g')
```

Obviously I know the above is not right, so does anyone know how I do this? I do not have the rights to run any PL/SQL.

Comment: what is the target string you wanna match

Comment: @vks I'm trying to find records where stu_insc does not match the regular expression mentioned above

Comment: See [REGEXP_LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm)

Comment: Have you tried google?  [first hit](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm#CHDBCCDJ)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On oracle you can try something along the lines of

```
select xyz
from theTable
where not regexp_like(mycolumn,pattern)
```